# Showing data in a grid

Tags: functions, list-manipulation, formatting, grid-layouts

I tried this code for one variable and it works fine.

```
Uexact[x_] := Exp[x]
Uapprox[x_] := 0.1*Exp[x]
Grid[Prepend[
  Table[{x , Uapprox[x], Uexact[x], 
    Abs[Uapprox[x] - Uexact[x]]  }, {x, -1, 1 , 0.5}], {"x", 
   "Approx", "exact", "Error"}], Frame -> All]
```

It gives the following
[image]

I tried this code for 2 variables.

```
Uexact[x_, t_] := Exp[x + t]
Uapprox[x_, t_] := 0.1*Exp[x + t]
Grid[Prepend[
  Table[{x , t, Uexact[x, t], Uapprox[x, t], 
    Abs[Uapprox[x, t] - Uexact[x, t]]  }, {x, -1, 1 , 0.2}, {t, 0, 1, 
    0.1}], {"x", "t", "Approx", "exact", "Error"}], Frame -> All]
```

How can I fix my code to show the result as the 1-variable example?

Answer (score 5):

One possible way is to use `Dataset`:

```
Clear[Uexact, Uapprox];
Uexact[x_, t_] := Exp[x + t]
Uapprox[x_, t_] := 0.1*Exp[x + t]

Dataset@Flatten@
  Table[
    AssociationThread[
       {"x", "t", "Approx", "exact", "Error"}, 
       {x, t, Uexact[x, t], Uapprox[x, t], Abs[Uapprox[x, t] - Uexact[x, t]]}
    ], {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {t, 0, 1, 0.1}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
Uexact[x_, t_] := Exp[x + t] 
Uapprox[x_, t_] := 0.1*Exp[x + t] 
Grid[Prepend[
  Table[{x, t, Uexact[x, t], Uapprox[x, t], 
     Abs[Uapprox[x, t] - Uexact[x, t]]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {t, 0, 1, 
     0.1}] // Catenate (* change here *), {"x", "t", "Approx", "exact", "Error"}], 
 Frame -> All]
```

Answer (score 2):

It suffices to `Flatten` the Table[...] :

```
  Uexact[x_, t_] := Exp[x + t]
    Uapprox[x_, t_] := 0.1*Exp[x + t]
    Grid[Prepend[
      Flatten[
       Table[{x, t, Uexact[x, t], Uapprox[x, t], 
         Abs[Uapprox[x, t] - Uexact[x, t]]}, {x, -1, 1, 0.2}, {t, 0, 1, 
         0.1}]
       , 1]
      , {"x", "t", "Approx", "exact", "Error"}], Frame -> All]
```

[image]